# I am looking for a php function that will prevent this: Undefined index: message in

Tags: php, forms, post

```
if(defined($_POST["message"]) && defined($_POST["name"]))
{
```

In that if block an exception is thrown constantly. I am looking for a function that will prevent this by testing if it the post variable exists..if it doesnt exists return false instead of throwing an exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST["message"]) && isset($_POST["name"])) {
    // ....
}
```

or if you want to check them to be not only set but also non-empty:

```
if (!empty($_POST["message"]) && !empty($_POST["name"])) {
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `isset()` for determining if a variable is set.  Use `defined()` to check if a constant is defined with the `define()` function.

See the Manual:

[defined function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)

[isset function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset` instead of `defined`.

```
if(isset($_POST["message"]) && isset($_POST["name"])) {
[...]
```

`defined` takes a string as an argument, and is for checking if a constant exists.